# Want to redirect a bunch of urls to another url structure in bulk with redirection plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, redirect

I have a Blogger blog and moved the site to WordPress.

I Want to redirect URLs like **www.example.com/2017/01/sample-post.html** or **www.example.com/year/month/sample-post.html** to URLs like **www.example.com/sample-post/** in bulk with the help of Redirection plugin using RegX method in WordPress.

Which regex source should I use? any help??

PS: this is my post on StackOverflow, mod move this to an appropriate category.

Comment: Is this a programming question? If so, please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried so far. What happens when you run it? Any errors? See also [ask]. If not, it's off-topic here; you could try https://wordpress.stackexchange.com instead. I'd also suggest you read [ask] first, though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any redirection plugin. Just follow these steps:

a) Goto Setting from your wordpress admin dashboard.

b)Goto Permalinks section in settings.

c)Selet option Post Name there and it'll become what you need.

Comment: I understand that but I want to redirect the old URLs to the new URLs for SEO purposes. Never mind I've done it successfully. What I did was installed the rank math plugin and set up the redirection module. Then I used regular expression (regex) and used the following code on source section: /yearnumber/monthnum/(.*).html and destination section pasted the following: $1/

Hope it helps to others who are migrating from blogger to wordpress

Comment: @PradipSingha sounds good. I'm glad that you solved your problem by your own :)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that but I want to redirect the old URLs to the new URLs for SEO purposes. Never mind I've done it successfully. What I did was installed the rank math plugin and set up the redirection module. Then I used regular expression (regex) and used the following code on source section: /yearnumber/monthnum/(.*).html and destination section pasted the following: $1/

Hope it helps others who are migrating from blogger to WordPress @khalidkhan

Answer (score 0):

You can use [yoast seo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin for both redirection and seo.